# android: updating media storage

Tags: android, mediastore

i was making an app that tries to record audio and also list all the audio files on the sdcard.

now i populate the list here from the MediaStore using cursors.

now the issue here is, every time an audio is recorded i need to wait for the OS to make a scan through the memory card so that my list gets updated with the newly recorded track.

so i was wondering if there was any way to update the mediastorage programatically every time i finish recording some audio? is there any API or any function provided in android to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html